# replacing missing values with mode in R

Tags: r, csv, mode

I want to replace missing or N/A values in a csv file with mode. The column consists of strings. Column name is "embarked".
I tried this

`embarked.mode <- mode(data$Embarked, na.rm=TRUE)
data$Embarked[is.na(data$Embarked)] = embarked.mode`

I am getting the following error

`Error in mode(data$Embarked, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)`

Please help me how to replace them with mode without impute.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode

Comment: `mode` is not the most common value but the storage mode of the object. e.g. `mode(1)` is 'numeric', `mode("abc")` character etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get the most frequent value,try:

```
names(which.max(table(data$Embarked,useNA="no")))
```